# Intent stub method getting called before actual code execution

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso

```
intending(hasAction(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)).respondWith(createImageCaptureActivityResultStub();

private createImageCaptureActivityResultStub() {
 //change value of imageUri
 Uri imageUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context.getApplicationContext(),
                context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName() + ".fileprovider", destination);
        MemberManipulator.setFieldValue(Utility.getActivityInstance(), "imageUri", imageUri);
}
```

Inside the `createImageCaptureActivityResultStub()`. I am manipulating the value of instance variable `imageUri`. This stub method should have been called when this line is getting executed, but it's getting called initially only. It's changing the value of `imageUri` before reaching this line of code.

```
startActivityForResult(intent, AppConstants.REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
```

Comment: can you please post your   `createImageCaptureActivityResultStub()` here

Comment: I debugged and found value of imageUri getting changed before intent is launched as stub method is getting exceuted before.

Comment: You can use `handler.postDelayed` to solve this issue

Comment: this is related to espresso testing. Stub method has to be called when intent is getting launched. Delaying doesn't make any sense here. Can you please explain.

Comment: Then Sorry, I don't have any Idea about espresso